# How to find the sum of that series related to Legendre functions of the second kind?

Tags: special-functions, summation

I mean $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{Q_n\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}{n+1}. $$

It's unclear to me whether the series under consideration converges. I have strong doubts concerning its closed form. My best is

```
NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, 200}]
(*0.307806*)
```

However, the command

```
NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

is running without any response for hours. Maple finds it, but Maple uses another definition of `LegendreQ[n, x]` and results in a complex number.

Comment: The true convergence of a series is its absolute convergence. However, `NSum[RealAbs[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 20, "Degree" -> 1}, 
 NSumTerms -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` is running without any respose for dozen minutes.

Comment: With `NSum`'s option setting `VerifyConvergence -> False` that computation runs for less than 0.03 on my laptop with Version 12.1.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Please, don't edit the title from "How to find,,," to "How can I find...". Do you understand me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update

One of the (brute force) estimates I posted earlier using the `Method` option:

```
 Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 200, "Degree" -> 2}
```

is in agreement with the estimates from [Bob Hanlon's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/233740) and [Ulrih Neumann's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/233778) answers:

```
0.3071246932
```

#### First comment/answer

*(Not an answer, extended comment -- I have to investigate some more when I have more time...)*

You can experiment with `NSum`'s methods and their options :

```
Options[NSum`WynnEpsilon]

(* {"ExtraTerms" -> 15, "Degree" -> 1} *)

 AbsoluteTiming[
 NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 200, "Degree" -> 1}, 
  NSumTerms -> 200, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
 ]

(* During evaluation of In[113]:= NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect. *)

(*{2.98816, 0.3067630883738178981725444510087078866354171794104} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 200, "Degree" -> 2}, 
  NSumTerms -> 200, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
 ]

(* During evaluation of In[114]:= NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect. *)

(* {2.95999, 0.3071246932} *)

Options[NSum`AlternatingSigns]

(*{"ExtraTerms" -> Automatic, "Method" -> None}*)

AbsoluteTiming[
 NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"AlternatingSigns", "ExtraTerms" -> 200}, 
  NSumTerms -> 200, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
 ]

(* {2.9436, 0.30778346567187937249641347178243295192965243540504244041119905365363\
13013362226542629291522107099502} *)
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for the options of `NSum`. As far as I understand "NumericalMathNSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect. ", you do not do the job as yet. Thank you anyway. I will be waiting when you will have more time...

Comment: Sorry, but the result of `Table[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, 16}] // N` does not show any alternating signs. Also how about `VerifyConvergence`? I will be waiting when you will have more time...

Comment: Thank you. I think about the accepting. Unfortunately, `NSum[RealAbs[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 200, "Degree" -> 2}]` is running without any response for dozen minutes.

Comment: With `NSum`'s option setting `VerifyConvergence -> False` that computation runs for less than 0.03 on my laptop with Version 12.1

Comment: `NSum[RealAbs[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity},   Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "ExtraTerms" -> 200, "Degree" -> 2}] ` produces `2.27213`.

Answer (score 11):

The result is

```
1/4 (ArcCosh[3] ArcSinh[1] -
ArcSinh[1 - Sqrt[2]] Log[7 - 4 Sqrt[2] - 2 Sqrt[2 (10 - 7 Sqrt[2])]])
```

You can get to it using the integral representation of LegendreQ and then
pulling the integral before the sum.

With this integral repesentation of LegendreQ (omitting a purely imaginary part)

```
I1=Integrate[(1/Sqrt[2] + I Cosh[t]/Sqrt[2])^(-1 - n), {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

you get

```
Sum[1/(n+1)I1,{n,0,Infinity}],
```

then exchange summation and integral to arrive at

```
Integrate[(-I (-I + 
 Cosh[t]) Log[(-I + I Sqrt[2] + Cosh[t])/(-I + Cosh[t])]/(Sqrt[
  2] (1/Sqrt[2] + (I Cosh[t])/Sqrt[2]))), {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

Now evaluate the antiderivative, enter the limits and take the real part of 
the result. By checking the remaining PolyLogs you find they are all zero.

For (-1<z<1) I get the more general result

```
Re[PolyLog[2, 2 /(1 - Sqrt[I Sqrt[1 - z^2] - z])] + PolyLog[2, 2 /(1 + Sqrt[I Sqrt[1 - z^2] - z])] - PolyLog[2, 2 /(1 - Sqrt[2 z (z - I Sqrt[1 - z^2]) - 1])] - PolyLog[2, 2 /(1 + Sqrt[2 z (z - I Sqrt[1 - z^2]) - 1])]]
```

The real part of the above is

```
ArcTanh[z]^2/2 + 1/2 Log[(Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[1 - z])/Sqrt[1 + z]]^2 + ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - z]/Sqrt[2]] Log[2] +1/2 (ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - z]/Sqrt[2]] +Log[2]) Log[(1 + z)/(3 + 2 Sqrt[2 - 2 z] - z)] + \[Pi]^2/24 + 1/2 Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]^2 + 1/4 PolyLog[2, -3 - 2 Sqrt[2]] + 1/4 PolyLog[2, -3 + 2 Sqrt[2]]
```

The derivation is along the line of the special case, I integrated only the real part of the integral representation to obtain a real expression.

We can even get rid of the PolyLog constants:

```
ArcTanh[z]^2/2 + ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - z]/Sqrt[2]] Log[2] + 1/2 Log[(Sqrt[2] - 
Sqrt[1 - z])/Sqrt[1 + z]]^2 + 1/2 (ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - z]/Sqrt[2]] + Log[2]) Log[(1 + z)/(3 + 2 Sqrt[2 - 2 z] - z)] - 4 ArcCoth[Sqrt[2]]^2 + 
4 ArcSinh[1]^2 + 2 ArcSinh[1 - Sqrt[2]] Log[7 - 4 Sqrt[2] - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[10 - 7 Sqrt[2]]] - Log[7 - 4 Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[10 - 7     Sqrt[2]]]^2
```

I noticed that this can further be simplified to a short and beautiful

```
ArcTanh[z]^2/2-ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - z]/Sqrt[2]]^2 + 
1/2 Log[(Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[1 - z])/Sqrt[1 + z]]^2.
```

And still shorter, so that we finally have:

```
Sum[LegendreQ[n, z]/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}] = 
(ArcTanh[z]^2 - Log[(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[1 - z])/Sqrt[1 + z]]^2)/2, (-1 < z < 1).
```

Comment: Er… Can you elaborate a bit more? Which integral representation do you choose?

Comment: I used http://functions.wolfram.com/07.10.07.0002.01

Comment: @Andreas: I see the condition `Re[z]>1` there, but `z==Sqrt[2]/2` and `z` is less than `1`.

Comment: I know, but my result matches the given numeric estimates anyway

Comment: @Andreas: Can you present your derivation in the forum? TIA.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you. That is in L. Euler's style. I still don't see the derivation of "the more general result".

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry, I don't undersiand your latest update though I am PhD in math for ages.  Can you elaborate it in details? TIA.

Comment: @Andreas: I think you make use of another definition of Legendre functions of second kind. The coincidence in the results is not fortuituos, so +1. I definitely end this discussion.

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Defining the sum recursively:

```
LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1) /. n -> 0 // Simplify

(* 1/2 Log[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]] *)

sum[0] = Log[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]]/2.0`20;

sum[m_Integer?Positive] := sum[m] =
  sum[m - 1] + LegendreQ[m, Sqrt[2]/2]/(m + 1)
```

Calculating the points for a plot (this is slow)

```
sum[1000]

(* 0.30718615098022934340 *)
```

Plotting,

```
ListPlot[Callout[sum[#], If[Mod[#, 4] == 2, #, ""]] & /@ Range[0, 1000], 
 DataRange -> {0, 1000}]
```

[image]

The sum converges slowly unless restricted to values of `m` such that `Mod[m, 4] == 2`

The sum is approximately,

```
approx = Mean[sum /@ {994, 998}]

(* 0.30712469378349263758 *)

Show[
 ListPlot[Callout[sum[#], #] & /@ Range[2, 998, 4], DataRange -> {2, 998}],
 Plot[approx, {x, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: -1. This is not it: you count partial sums. Are you serious?

Comment: @user64494 - I don't understand your comment. I am plotting the partial sum as a function of the number of terms. This is a fairly normal way of looking at the convergence of a sum. As the number of terms increase, the partial sum converges slowly. However, the subset of partial sums with the number of terms equal to 2 mod 4 converges faster. The labels are used to highlight these values of the number of terms. It is more efficient to work with this subset to get an approximate value for the infinite sum.

Comment: There is not an  infinite sum. There is a notion of the sum of a series which involves the limit.

Comment: I wonder the upvoters. See the comments to a serious answer by Anton Antonov.

Comment: @user64494 …Do you think Bob has calculated $\frac{Q_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}{2+1}+\frac{Q_6\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}{6+1}+\frac{Q_{10}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}{10+1}+…$ instead? If so, your understanding for his answer is wrong, please check his code carefully.

Comment: @xzczd: In any case Bob Hanlon calculates partial sums, not the sums of series. This is not it. Amn't I right?

Comment: @user64494 You mentioned `NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, 200}]` in your question as your best, don't you?

Comment: @xzczd:  The calculation of `NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, 200}]` took much time and did not solve the problem of the convergence. Because of that I gave up wit partial sums. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 Then Bob has shown the partial sum _seems_ to converge, and when `Mod[m, 4] == 2`, `NSum[LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]/(n + 1), {n, 0, m}]` converges faster. A `ListPlot` isn't a strict proof of course, but it's not surprising the answer gets upvotes. Also, as mentioned in the **Details and Options** section of document of `NSum`, "…with sufficiently pathological summands, the algorithms used by `NSum` can give wrong answers. In most cases, you can test the answer by looking at its sensitivity to changes in the setting of options for `NSum`", so `NSum` won't prove convergency either.

Comment: @xzczd: The behavior of `LegendreQ[n, Sqrt[2]/2]]/(n + 1)` is not pathological: four positive terms are followed by four negative terms.and so on. Their absolute values seem monotinically decrease.

Comment: Also see [Absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) concerning the rearrangement.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for your post! It produces an estimate which is in agreement with one of my "brute force" computed estimates.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @BobHanlon's very interesting answer one can proceed a little bit forward to get an approximated limit( !not a proof, only applied numerics!) .

As Bob mentioned there is a dominant harmonic in the solution `sum[m]~a+b Sin[2Pi (t-c)/8]`, which might be detected by `Fouriertransformation`.

Alternatively I try `NonlinearModelFit` to get the harmonic

```
data = Table[{m, sum[m]}, {m, 900, 1000}];
mod = NonlinearModelFit[data, {a + b Sin[2 Pi (t - c)/8] }, {a, b, c},t]
fit = mod["BestFitParameters"]
limit = a /. fit (*best guess: 0.307124 *)
```

The approximated limit is  0.307124.

```
Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[mod[t], {t, 900, 1000}]}, PlotRange -> All,GridLines -> {None, {{limit, {Thickness[.01], Red} }}  }]
```

[image]

Comment: I have never heard about "an approximated limit". Think of  a scientific publication.

Comment: Perhaps "asymptotic limit" ?

Comment: Nice approach -- it produces an estimate which is in agreement with one of my "brute force" computed estimates.